# Image and Text all in one line

Tags: css

Hey guys I have a page [here](http://gringlishgirl.com/test/contact/):

where I want the flag the h3 to be in one perfect line:

```
<h3>CONTACT MY AGENT</h3>

<img src="http://gringlishgirl.com/test/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/canada.png" align="left" />

<h3 style="font-size: 20px; padding-bottom: 5px;">CANADA</h3>

<strong>Film Comm Talent &amp; Model Agency</strong>
http://filmcomm.ca/
Hudson’s Bay Centre
Bloor Street East. Suite 3500
Toronto, ON M4W 1A8
phone: 416-915-3103
email: agents@filmcomm.ca
```

I used align="left" to make it happen and work with padding-bottom but no effect.

Any idea how to put them on one line like this perfectly??:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider something like:

```
<div class='canada-wrapper'>
  <img src='http://gringlishgirl.com/test/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/canada.png'>
  <h3>CANADA</h3>
</div>
```

And your CSS:

```
.canada-wrapper {
  // keep absolute positioning of the image within the wrapper
  position: relative;
}

.canada-wrapper img {
  // position 50% from the top, and offset by -50% using transforms
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.canada-wrapper h3 {
  // push the text to the right of the image
  // (fine tune as desired)
  margin-left: 48px;
}
```

The magic here is `transform: translateY`, which will perfectly vertically align the image - regardless of the size of the text next to it. It surprisingly has good [cross-browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#Browser_compatibility) (modern browser and IE9+). You'll just need to prefix accordingly with `-moz`, etc.

JSFiddle (does not include webfonts): https://jsfiddle.net/6q7tLucn/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vertical-align` for the image

```
img.your_class {
   vertical-align:-2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... I looked at the HTML and it looks like your `<img />` is inside of a `<p>` tag.

One thing you can do is give the `<p>` tag and the `<h3>` tag a class of "inline-insertwhateverhere" and then give that class the following rule:

```
.inline-elements {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; /* just in case; remove if unneeded */
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Then you can play with the margin, padding, maybe mess with the height to make it look like you want. You may end up giving the `<p>` tag and the `<h3>` tag separate class names, such as "ca-flag" and "country-name" and then replace
`.inline-elements` with `.ca-flag, .country-name` so you can customize each element more specifically.

Answer (score 0):

You may just add `float:left` to your image tag.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <img src="http://gringlishgirl.com/test/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/canada.png" class="ClsImg"><h3>CANADA</h3>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.ClsImg{
  float:left;
}
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/shishirmax/bv4qrfg3/)

Answer (score 0):

Apply the below styles

```
  .wpb_wrapper p + p{
    clear: both;
  }
    .wpb_wrapper h3 + p {
    clear: both;
        float: left;
        margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    width: auto;
    }
    .wpb_wrapper h3 + p + h3, .wpb_wrapper h3 ~ p + h3 {
        clear: none;
        padding: 0;
        line-height: 24px;
    }
```